# How to generate php code with classname prefix using thrift

Tags: php, thrift

For example:

I write a thrift file with a namespace `com`

```
namespace com;
struct xxx {
}
```

and I exepected the code thrift generates like this:

```
class com_xxx {

}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use '_' in a class name?
I'm not sure I understand. May be you mean this one?
namespace com; class xxx{}. Then its generated class com\xxx{}.

Answer (score 1):

Thrift will generate a class like that for you

```
<?php
namespace com;

class xxx {

}

?>
```

And you can use this class any where by "use com\xxx".

In your case, I think that maybe you don't understand what namespace is and how it is used. "namespace" keyword on Thrift respect with **namespace** on PHP, you can read here artict to know http://www.sitepoint.com/php-53-namespaces-basics. It is not a method to change PHP file form that is generated by Thrift.

If you really want to do that, you should do as (without namespace):

> struct com_xxx {
>
> }